# jQuery -> mouseEnter change css till number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS and jQuery code. What I want to do is:

On star mouse enter, `fade in`. If the star with `id=4` is hovered, fade in all stars before 4, if till 3, then only fade in first 3 stars. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var rating = $('#rating').val();
        $('.giveRating').click(function(){
            var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#rating').val(clicked);
            $(this).css({opacity: 1});
            $(this).prevAll('.giveRating').css({opacity:1});
        })

        //Change css on mouseEnter to new CSS
        $('.giveRating').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).prevAll('.giveRating').css({opacity:1});
            $(this).css({opacity: 1});

        });

        //Change CSS on mouseLeave to old CSS
        $('.giveRating').mouseleave(function(){
            $('.giveRating').css({opacity: 0.5});
        });
    });
</script>

echo '<img class="giveRating" id="1" src="'.url('images/pages/reviews/star.png').'">';
echo '<img class="giveRating" id="2" src="'.url('images/pages/reviews/star.png').'">';
echo '<img class="giveRating" id="3" src="'.url('images/pages/reviews/star.png').'">';
echo '<img class="giveRating" id="4" src="'.url('images/pages/reviews/star.png').'">';
echo '<img class="giveRating" id="5" src="'.url('images/pages/reviews/star.png').'">';
```

Comment: And the issue you're experiencing is...?

Comment: I can change the .css of 1 star, but not all of them.

Comment: That's what you have written the code to do.

Comment: Yeah i know, but  now my question is: how can i make the stars glowing till the id that is hovered: hover on ID3: star 1,2,3 gets an opacity of 1. Star 5 hovered, all stars gain an opacity of 1

Comment: Your code targets the class giveRating with the same function.  If you want different behavior for each star, you'll need to provide specific functionality targeted to specific elements.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: using Danko's images http://jsfiddle.net/v69Dw/

Answer (score 2):

This should give you an idea of how to start.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var rating = $('#rating').val();
        $('.giveRating').click(function(){
            var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#rating').val(clicked);
        })

        //Change css on mouseEnter to new CSS
        $('.giveRating').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).prevAll('.giveRating').css({opacity:1});
            $(this).css({opacity: 1});
        });

        //Change CSS on mouseLeave to old CSS
        $('.giveRating').mouseleave(function(){
            $('.giveRating').css({opacity: 0.5});
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sP4GZ/

Update (Click functionality)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timeOut;
    var hasClicked;

        var rating = $('#rating').val();
        $('.giveRating').click(function(){
            hasClicked = true;
            var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
            clicked.prevAll('.giveRating').css({opacity:1});
            clicked.css({opacity: 1});
            $('#rating').val(clicked);
        })

        //Change css on mouseEnter to new CSS
        $('.giveRating').mouseenter(function(){
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            $(this).prevAll('.giveRating').css({opacity:1});
            $(this).css({opacity: 1});
            $(this).nextAll('.giveRating').css({opacity:0.5});
        });

        //Change CSS on mouseLeave to old CSS
        $('.giveRating').mouseleave(function(){
            if(!hasClicked){
                timeOut = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.giveRating').css({opacity: 0.5});
                },200);
            }
            hasClicked = false;
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sP4GZ/2/

Update 3

http://jsfiddle.net/v69Dw/

Comment: +1 beat me by a minute .. an example wiht [Animate](http://jsfiddle.net/92Qdf/) @DonnyvanV

Comment: @Danko Nice I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do it :)

Comment: Thank you Danko, looks smoother :) @trevor: whats the point of the timeout?

Comment: @DonnyvanV check my update for an improved example (gets rid of some of the flickering when hovering off an image)

Comment: @DonnyvanV oh the timeout does the same thing as `stop` as in `Danko's` example.. Basically it's just there so that the starts don't start fading while you are moving from one star to the next.  Would be cleaner to use stop.. I'm going to add another fiddle.

Comment: Ahhh nice, ill take a look on it :) btw, i changed my code with a on click function. Can you take a look on it? On click, the stars need to stays with an opacity of 1. On mouseleave, the stars while fade out like i sayed in the mouseleave function. See my own post

Comment: @DonnyvanV yeah i'll take a look.

Comment: @DonnyvanV I have a update, but I need to make it better give me 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Take your time. Please also explain the rules so i can learn from it :) Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45227/discussion-between-trevor-and-donny-van-v)

Comment: @DonnyvanV please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Is there a way to send private messages on stackoverflow?